# Php and mysql filter

Tags: php, mysql, filter

I'm trying to create a filter in mysql and php. In my database, I have many fields like : name, phoneNumber, email... And even if I do something like

```
if(!empty($_POST['name'])){ 
$name=$_POST['name']
}
if(!empty($_POST['phoneNumber'])){ 
   $phoneNumber= $_POST['phoneNumber']
    }
if(!empty($_POST['email'])){ 
    $email=$_POST['email']
    }
```

If someone only enters the name field, how do I do to not include the other fields in the query?

```
$query=query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE clientName=$clientName && phoneNumber=$phoneNumber && email=$email)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like given below

```
if(!empty($_POST['name'])){ 
$name=$_POST['name'];
$query="SELECT * FROM clients WHERE clientName='$name'";
}
if(!empty($_POST['phoneNumber'])){ 
   $phoneNumber= $_POST['phoneNumber'];
   $query.= " AND phoneNumber='$phoneNumber'";
    }
if(!empty($_POST['email'])){ 
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $query.= " AND email='$email'";
    }
```

> NOTE:use prepared query because this is open to sql injection attack.
>   this is demonstration only.

Answer (score 1):

What I do for this sort of thing is have all the search terms sent to post within a single JSON object. So in javascript I collect all the search inputs and have an object where each key corresponds to the name of the input and each value corresponds to the val. For example in jQuery

```
var searchObj = {};
$(".searchInput").each(function() {
     searchObj[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});
var searchJSON = JSON.stringify(searchObj);
//later send searchJSON to php

//in php
$seachObj = json_decode($_POST["searchJSON"], true);
$sql = "SELECT * in CLIENTS WHERE ";
foreach($searchObj as $key => $val) {
    $sql .= "$key = '$val' AND ";
}
$sql .= "1";
```

NOW THIS IS TOTALLY UNSECURED!!! Only included so that it's clear. Better to use PDO or mysqli, to use prepared statements. Like this:

```
$seachObj = json_decode($_POST["searchJSON"], true);
$sql = "SELECT * in CLIENTS WHERE ";
$vals = [];
foreach($searchObj as $key => $val) {
    $vals[] = $val;
    $sql .= "$key = ? AND ";
}
$sql .= "1";
//learn more about PDO to get this part
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($vars);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this would do it.

```
$condition = "";

if(!empty($_POST['name'])){ 
$name=$_POST['name'];
$condition .= " AND clientName LIKE ".$name;
}
if(!empty($_POST['phoneNumber'])){ 
   $phoneNumber= $_POST['phoneNumber'];
    $condition .= " AND phoneNumber ='".$phoneNumber."'";
}
if(!empty($_POST['email'])){ 
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $condition .= " AND email='".$email."'";
}

if(!empty($condition)){
   $query="SELECT * FROM clients WHERE ".ltrim($condition," AND");
}else{
   $query="SELECT * FROM clients";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I try your code, this mistake appears : Warning: PDO::query(): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'qsfd' inconnu dans where clause in C:\wamp64\www\applocations\gestion-client.php on line 39. Do you know why?